# how to set "objects" property in aframe raycaster component

Tags: aframe

I want to use `raycaster` component in `<a-cursor>` entity to intersect some
 cubes.
I set the `objects` property like '#box' (my cube's id), but the cursor still 
intersects all element.
I step into the raycaster source code, and the `data.objects` is `''` .
So, I wonder if I set the property in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in A-Frame with dependency components. It's been fixed in the Dev Builds: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/tree/master/dist#dev-builds and will be released with 0.4.0.

A workaround is to put the raycaster component before the cursor:

```
<a-entity raycaster="..." cursor="..."></a-entity>
```