# A-frame (VR) picking of nested entities

Tags: aframe, webvr

Im grouping `<a-box>`'es with a `<a-entity>` wrapper.
Then, Im using the cursor component in the `<scene>` and trying to pick/select individual objects that make up the `<a-entity>` wrapper, yet only wrapper `<a-entity>` gets selected, not the individual objects.

Im really curious about this. I looked at all the aframe **cursor** (https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/components/cursor.html) docs, and there is no specific mention of this scenario. It does mention that the **raycaster**(https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/components/raycaster.html) used by the **cursor** returns the first entity that is intersecting with the projected ray... which would be the grouped entity... so always returning it makes sense.

everything works fine when all the `<a-box>`'es are attached to the global `<a-scene>`, and they can be selected individually.

Am I correct to assume that picking only works correctly when the particular object is a global entity (not a nested one)?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. you can add a `raycaster` component to cursor entity. and set specific objects which you want to pick. you can see this question I asked before [how to set “objects” property in aframe raycaster component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522866/how-to-set-objects-property-in-aframe-raycaster-component) .

Comment: I tried this already, it doesnt work...  
<a-entity raycaster="objects: .v3d_cube" cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 100"...>.
All objects that I want to be selectable have a "v3d_cube" class added to them

Comment: I modified `raycaster` component source code, like this ```init: function () {
    this.direction = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.intersectedEls = [];
    this.objects = [];
    this.prevCheckTime = undefined;
    this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    this.updateOriginDirection();
  },```

Comment: sorry, i can't edit my last comment. and I modified raycaster component `refreshObjects` function, noted `this.objects = []` in line 58521. then I registered a `update-raycaster` component. code is `AFRAME.registerComponent('update-raycaster', {
  schema: {type: 'selector'},

  init: function () {
    var raycasterEl = this.data;
    raycasterEl.components.raycaster.data.objects="#"+this.el.id;
    raycasterEl.components.raycaster.refreshObjects();
  }
});`. add this `update-raycaster="#cursor"` component to which entity you want to pick. sorry for my English. wish my words be useful

Comment: I tried your suggested code.
its throwing an error 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined(…)

Comment: I don't know how you got this error. if I can see your code, maybe I would find the problem. and I wrote a demo published at [link](https://solitaire2015.github.io/aframe-demo.github.io/). I group two boxes in sphere, I add `update-raycaster="#cursor"` to the pink box. so, only the pink box can be selected.